# mapState on non-namespaced module

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I have a module

```
export default {
  namespaced: false,
  state,
  actions,
  mutations,
  getters
};
```

In my component I have tried these:

```
 ...mapState(["user"]),
 ...mapState('auth',["user"]),
```

but neither of them work, instead I have to use this as a computed property:

```
user() { return this.$store.state.auth.user; },
```

Is it possible to use ...mapState?

Comment: `...mapState({ authUser: state => state.auth.user })`

Comment: @RichardMatsen, this works, however, it is still quite verbose, is there a way using the syntax similar to what im trying with ...mapstate? it works if the module is namespaced and i use ...mapState('auth',["user"]),, but not without

Comment: Write a getter.

Comment: @RichardMatsen, a mapGetter works good thanks

Comment: fyi a proposition has been made here for VueJS3: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1592

Answer (score 2):

#### mapGetters

The most efficient way with **non-namespaced** modules is to define a getter. The advantage is that you don't have to redefine it in every component you want to use the property in.

```
getters: {
  user: state => state.user,
}
```

```
...mapGetters([
  "user",
]),
```

This stands in oposition to some beliefs that you "shouldn't overuse getters", but it's a sad reality that this is one thing Vuex got wrong. Since non-namespaced modules share their namespace with the root state, their props should be available right away as well, but they aren't.

#### mapState

If you want to use mapState instead, I don't think nested destructuring syntax is any good for that:

```
...mapState({
  user: ({ auth: { user } }) => user,
}),
```

This is not readable at all. This doesn't make your code any shorter, as you need to repeat the prop name anyway. This is the way to go:

```
...mapState({
  user: state => state.auth.user,
}),
```